# Change AccessToken Table in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I am new to loopback, I am trying to change the accessToken table stored in MySQL. I have myUser table and the myUser model is extended from User model and if i login through myUser the accessToken is storing in accessToken table, I want to change the accesToken table to myAccessToken Table, Is is possible to change the destination of accessToken data to any other table.
can anybody help me to fix this issue

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `server.js`:

```js
app.use(loopback.token({
  model: app.models.myAccessToken
}))
```

Comment: What happens if I have multiple subclasses of AccessToken?

Comment: You may want to design your classes using polymorphic relations: http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Polymorphic-relations.html